# How to prevent persistent XSS attack in php?

Tags: xss

**Persistent XSS**, where the malicious string originates from the website's database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: I already knew the fixes for reflected XSS and DOM based XSS attack.